# returning the largest or smallest result from a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Suppose chest is a list of coordinates that are two item lists.

For example chest = [[2,4], [4,5], [1,3]]

With the function below, I want the distance between the point (x,y) and each of the chest points.  So as it is, the function would return these three distances, right?  But my question is, how do I return only the smallest (or largest) result from these three values?  Is there any way to do this without creating a new list of distances?

def makeMove(board, chest, x, y):

```
for cx, cy in chests:
    distance = sqrt(abs((x-cx)**2) + abs((y-cy)**2)))
    return distance
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `abs(x - cx)` instead of `abs(x) - abs(cx)` (and respectively for y)? The latter is guaranteed to give a non-negative value while the latter is incorrect for negative values and crashes if the difference is < 0. Also, stylistic nitpicking: Use tuples for fixed-length immutable sequences such as points and don't put spaces around function invokation parens (as in the second `abs` call).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `max()` or `min()` plus a generator expression...

```
return max(
    sqrt( abs(x - cx) + abs(y - cy) )
    for cx, cy in chests)
```

Also note that as an optimization, you may prefer to do this instead (since if `sqrt(x) > sqrt(y)`, then `x > y`) to reduce the number of `sqrt` calls:

```
return sqrt(max(
    abs(x - cx) + abs(y - cy)
    for cx, cy in chests))
```

(Also, are you sure you don't want to be squaring the distances instead of `abs()`ing them? The normal distance formula is `sqrt((x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2)`...)

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your function returns only the first distance.  When the `return` statement is encountered during the first loop iteration, the function returns, and that's it.

Furthermore, your formula for the distance is probably wrong, since the argument of `sqrt()` can get negative.  In the code below, I'm assuming you want the Euclidean distance instead.

While you can get the minimum and the maximum using generator expressions, this would require to compute all the distances twice.  Building on the loop you wrote, you could do

```
def distance_squared(p0, p1):
    return sum((x0 - x1) ** 2 for x0, x1 in zip(p0, p1))

def makeMove(board, chest, x, y):
    chest_iter = iter(chest)
    min_dist = distance_squared(next(chest_iter), (x, y))
    max_dist = min_dist
    for c in chest_iter:
        dist2 = distance_squared(c, (x, y))
        min_dist = min(min_dist, dist2)
        max_dist = max(max_dist, dist2)
    return sqrt(min_dist), sqrt(max_dist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max_distance = max([sqrt((abs(x) - abs (cx)) + (abs(y) - abs(cy))) for cx, cy in chests])
min_distance = min([sqrt((abs(x) - abs (cx)) + (abs(y) - abs(cy))) for cx, cy in chests])
```

Basically you turn the loop into a list comprehension, (so you are in fact creating a new list), and call `max` and `min` to get the smallest members from the new list of distances.

Comment: No reason to use a list comprehension when a generator expression would suffice.